# How to apply conditional formatting to pivot table dynamically

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, webdatarocks

I would like to set conditional formatting in webdatarocks like this:

```
"conditions": [
        {
            "formula": "AND(#value > 5000, #value < 8000)",
            "format": {
                "backgroundColor": "#3cff00",
                "color": "#FFFFFF"
            }
        }
    ],
```

But with code, not via user interface.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Also, can I apply conditional formatting to calculated measures?